# Integrating Spring Security with CXF OSGI bundle running in Karaf

Tags: spring, osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

The application I am working with has a Web Application Bundle with JavaScript-based client, which issues REST calls to a CXF-based bundle. The latter uses blueprint to hook up with services exposed by the service layer bundles. The main WAB uses Spring Security through Spring's DelegatingFilterProxy.

The goal is to intergate the CXF-based bundle into the security fold. We tried two approaches: deploying the CXF bundle as a WAB (registering the CXF servlet in it along with the Spring filter). The problem was in parsing the blueprint file which connects this bundle to the service layer. The specific error indicated the a namespace handler for blueprint could not be found.

The latest approach is to use blueprint.xml to deploy the CXFNonSpringServlet as well as to register DelegatingFilterProxy filter. The relevant section of blupring.xml:

```
   <service interface="javax.servlet.Servlet">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="servlet-name" value="ozpCXFServlet"/>
            <entry key="alias" value="/ozp/rest" />
        </service-properties>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet">
            <property name="bus" ref="cxfBus"/>
        </bean>
    </service>


    <service interface="javax.servlet.Filter">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="filter-name" value="springSecurityFilterChain"/>
            <entry key="servletNames">
                <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                    <value>ozpCXFServlet</value>
                </array>
            </entry>
            <entry key="urlPatterns">
                <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                    <value>/ozp/rest</value>
                </array>
            </entry>
        </service-properties>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy" />
    </service>
```

This part works and the filter gets integrated into the HTTP request. The error I get is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:159)
```

How do I avoid this error? How to assure the Spring application context get created?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spring-dm in this case. You are probably bound to the 2.5.x version of spring.
You probably neeed something like a OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext in your war.

Comment: We are trying what you suggested. However we ran into problem with OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext class, for which we are using an ugly hack. Without it, we are getting an error "bundle context should be set before refreshing the application context". In the class above, the call servletContext.getAttribute(BUNDLE_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE) returns null. The BUNDLE_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE at the time of the call is available on the outer class of the servlet context (I believe the classes come from Jetty). The hack uses reflection to extract the bundle context. Have you encountered such an issue?

Comment: nope, at least I can't remember seeing such an issue. 
Take a look at https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-488, maybe this gives you some pointers ...